# Butter vs Lard vs Palm oil

Tags: nutrition, oil

Palm oil is demonized a lot. I know that it contains a lot of polyunsaturated fats. The same thing is known about any animal fats including those in butter, cheese or lard. But these products are considered not so bad. Especially in the latest years after some researches that doubt connection between heart diseases and fats. So does it mean palm oil is only exactly as bad as butter? Or is it even worse for some reason?

Comment: I wish I knew the answer to this question. The only trustworthy looking source on this topic that I've found so far is the WHO bulletin. It mentions that "a meta-analysis  of  increased  palm  oil  consumption  in  23  countries  found  a  significant  relationship  with  higher  mortality from ischaemic heart disease."

https://www.who.int/bulletin/volumes/97/2/18-220434.pdf

It's not obvious though what exactly it means for end consumer. I'd love to get some expert opinion on this.